# split function not working in if statment Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

```
var text = "Q!123"; //Setting variable
if(isNaN(text.split('')[text.indexOf("!") + 1]) != true){ //Checking if character after the ! is a number
    return true; //Return true if true
}else{
    return false; //Return false if false
}
```

At the if statment where I have text.split(''), im not able to use it whilst grabbing a character from the array

Comment: isNaN tests for a specific value, not whether the string cannot be converted to a valid number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you write this match statement in if to check after '!' is number or not

```js
var text = "Q!123";
let match = text[text.indexOf("!") + 1].match(/[0-9]/)

console.log(match)
```